# segment size in bio

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I have a basic question about the bio struct in linux :

Do the segments in bio indicate only physically contiguous location of any size . if yes can a segment represent an area that is less than a sector in size? 
OR:
Do they correspond to 1 buffer which is defined in some texts as 1 block. (So a segment always points to n*sectors, where n>0).

Comment: I am talking about the block bio or the bio"s" . I had the question written with bios and it was edited to BIOS . So my question is about the segments in the bio structs used for IO and sent down from the FS to the block layer. I've updated the question with the right semantics.Thanks !